# XSLT: How to emulate an IF-ELSE clause

Tags: if-statement, xslt

Problem:

```
IF COND1 = true
{
    WHEN COND2 = TRUE
    {
        PRINT X1
    }
    OTHERWISE 
    {
        WHEN COND3 = TRUE {PRINT X2}
        OTHERWISE {PRINT X3}
    }
}
```

I have use  for COND1 and  ,  for COND2 and COND3 but its printing value X1 for all conditions. Can someone pls tell me how to apply above scenario?

```
<xsl:if test="($Id='5')">
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="(Cond='') "></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(Cond='true')or(Cond='Y')">Y</xsl:when>                                                                                   
<xsl:otherwise>N</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
</xsl:otherwise>    
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Learn about the `xsl:choose` instruction.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have used    xsl:choose still problem is not solved

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have added the example in question.

Comment: As you write it, Cond is not a variable but treated as node. If you have a variable named Cond and want to use that, write `$Cond`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you

```
<xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                        
    <xsl:when test="($Id='5') and (Cond='')"></xsl:when>                                                                      
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(Cond='true') or (Cond='Y')">Y</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>N</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>                             
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks this solution really helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no IF-ELSE in XSLT.
But you can use `<xsl:if>` and `<xsl:choose>` - as @michael.hor257k suggested - with an identical outcome.

So here is the pseudo-code equivalent of your sample code:

```
<xsl:if test="COND1 = TRUE">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="COND2 = TRUE">
      PRINT X1
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="COND3 = TRUE">
          PRINT X2
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          PRINT X3
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Same solution i have applied, you can see the code snippet in question. It is not working. It will print X1 for each condition.

Comment: @Lipi: You still haven't provided a [mcve], so I can neither approve nor deny your criticism.

Comment: i have provided the code snippet in question. Please scroll down the question @zx485

Comment: It's not COMPLETE. It's not a complete stylesheet and you haven't supplied a source document. We can't run it, therefore we can't debug it. We don't know what the input conditions are. From the code given, I can't see how it can possibly output X1: all branches output Y, N, or nothing.

Comment: Someone has downvoted my question without leaving a comment. This is ridiculous, if they can not solve this problem they will downvoted it.